# Bloquear acesso de usuários com IP's estrangeiros

Tags: php, mysql, ip

É possível restringir o acesso a um determinado site ou sistema Web, de forma que só IP's do Brasil consigam acessa-lo?

Tenho um mini-sistema em PHP, e para aumentar ainda mais a sua segurança, gostaria de colocá-lo inacessível para todo tipo de acesso estrangeiro. A princípio, pensei em configurar alguma(s) faixa(s) de IP(s) específica(s) de países estrangeiros, de modo que qualquer acesso oriundo desse parâmetro fosse bloqueado.

Com estas informações de IP's em mãos, iria criar então uma tabela no MySql, e então realizaria a validação de acesso no PHP.

Mesmo que não seja possível mapear todas as faixas de IP's necessárias, só o fato de eliminar alguma coisa, já irá contribuir para a segurança do sistema.

Já 'blindei' a minha aplicação para evitar ataques do tipo XSS e SQL Injection, etc. Implementei também diversas validações de segurança.

Agora, o que gostaria mesmo, é implementar essa validação por IP.

Comment: Tem a API de geoip. Já leu sobre?

Comment: vou dar uma lida nisso. obrigado Alex.

Comment: eu decidi responder com um projeto que tenho aqui. Espero que seja útil de alguma forma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom, tive o mesmo problema um tempo atrás, mas consegui juntar a solução de uma API com algumas soluções próprias em PHP, nada extraordinário, afinal, é a API que faz tudo praticamente.

Irei usar nomes genéricos para as nomeações dos arquivos, mas consegui com a ajuda da API de GEOIP, daí bastou criar a parte de PHP e MySQL, o qual espero ser útil para você.

antes, você precisa se cadastrar para receber seu token via e-mail: https://www.localizaip.com.br/api_localiza_ip.php

Depois disto, basta alterar as linhas dos arquivos corretamente.

**index.php**

```
<script language="javascript">
var LIP_LowPrecision = false; //false = ask permission to the browser, higher precision | true = don't ask permission, lower precision
function LocalizaIP_done(ip_data){
    if (!ip_data['error']) //this line is an exemple, you must change it by your Geolocation manipulation code
        var pais = ip_data["countryCode"];

        $.ajax({
            data: 'pais=' + pais,
            url: 'processa.php',
            method: 'POST', // or GET
            success: function(msg) {
                //alert(msg);

                if(msg == 'banido'){
                    window.location="http://meusite.com.br/404/";
                }
            }
        });
}
</script>

<script src="https://www.localizaip.com/api/geolocation.js.php?domain=meusite.com.br&token=MEU_TOKEN=="></script>
```

**processa.php**

```
<?php
    $hostname_conexao = "localhost";
    $username_conexao = "root";
    $password_conexao = "";
    $database_conexao = "teste";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname_conexao, $username_conexao, $password_conexao, $database_conexao);

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }

    $pais = $_POST['pais'];

    $query  = "SELECT pais FROM banirips WHERE pais='".$pais."'";

    if($stmt_count = $mysqli->query($query))
    {
        $count_results = $stmt_count->num_rows;
        $stmt_count->close();   
    }

    if($count_results >= 1){echo "banido";}
?>
```

**banirips.sql**

```
id | pais |
1  |  AR  |
2  |  BR  |
```

Você deve salvar apenas o código do país desejado em seu banco de dados. O sistema vai comparar o quê estão salvo e bloqueará o acesso. Basta faze um teste com "BR" em seu banco de dados. Insira no BD e faça algo do tipo depois de puxar os dados:

Digamos que a variável "país"

```
if($pais == 'BR')
{
echo "PAÍS BLOQUEADO!";
}
else
{
echo "PAÍS SEM RESTRIÇÃO DE ACESSO!";
}
```

É algo assim que deseja?

Comment: exatamente Alex!  vou implementar essa estrutura no meu sistema. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Disponha, amigo ^^ Boa sorte

Comment: -1. Você está confiando totalmente no cliente, ele mesmo pode manipular a resposta do "www.localizaip.com" ou então bloquear o carregamento do conteúdo do "www.localizaip.com", que então poderá acessar o seu site normalmente. Assim como os usuários que possuem JS desabilitado ou que usem o "modo de leitura" do navegador, ou até mesmo queles que carregam a página e pausam o carregamento assim que vê o conteúdo. Isso é totalmente burlável, sem necessidade de proxies ou vpn.

Comment: Conhecendo uma ferramenta, há de se conhecer outras, colega. Nada impede que ele possa estudar alguma outra API. Eu dei uma solução para a resposta da pergunta. Agora se quer um sistema completo à prova de XSS e tudo quanto é tipo de hacking, creio que não seja o local correto. O Stack é não é depósito de sistemas. É um local onde se dá uma direção e o caminho quem faz somos nós.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, é possível restringir o acesso a um determinado site ou sistema web, de forma que só ips do Brasil consigam acessa-lo. Necessário uma tabela conforme mostrado no item 3 abaixo.

- 1 - Obtenha o `Ip` do visitante `$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`
- 2 - transforma o `Ip` em ip longo `$ipno = sprintf('%u', ip2long($ipaddress));`
- 3 - Selecione a sigla do pais (countrySHORT) de acordo com o ip longo `$query  = "SELECT countrySHORT FROM tbl_ipcountry WHERE ".$ipno." BETWEEN ipFROM AND ipTO";` [image: tabela]

  - Neste site  é possível  [**comprar**](https://www.ip2location.com/) ou fazer  [**download free**](https://lite.ip2location.com/) do data base
- 4 - Compare o valor retornado, se `BR` acesso livre.

**PHP**

```
//'** conexão com banco de dados
      $mysqli = new mysqli(....);

//'** Obtenção do Ip do visitante
    $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


//'** busca do país de origem da visita

    //transforma o ip em ip longo
    $ipno = sprintf('%u', ip2long($ipaddress));

    echo $ipno;

    //selecione a sigla do pais (countrySHORT) de acordo com o ip longo
    $query  = "SELECT countrySHORT FROM tbl_ipcountry WHERE ".$ipno." BETWEEN ipFROM AND ipTO";

        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {   
           $Nome_Pais = $row['countrySHORT'];
        }

    //se for diferente de BR direciona para
    if($Nome_Pais!="BR"){

       header('Location: http://dominio.com/404.php');

    }
```

> ip2long ( $ip_address ) - converte uma seqüência de caracteres ASCII contendo um endereço de Internet válido usando a notação de ponto (IP) em um integer (IP longo).
>   Um exemplo de notação de ponto é 120.121.5.123.
>
> A função ip2long() se torna muito útil, quando se faz necessário armazenar endereços de IP em um banco de dados, reduzindo consideravelmente o espaço utilizado, além de tornar muito mais rápida uma futura consulta por esses endereços de IP.
>   A redução de espaço se dá por que ao invés de armazenar o endereço de IP como uma string – 121.122.123.124 – e utilizando para tal um campo do tipo char(15), o que gastaria 15 bytes, você pode pode armazená-lo como um integer – 2130706433 – e gastar 4 bytes ao invés de 15.

Comment: Obrigado Léo, vou dar uma olhada nisso. Abçs.

Comment: Boa alternativa, Léo

Answer (score -2):

Eu estou desenvolvendo uma especie de analytics e me deparei com esse desafio.
Resolvi esse problema utilizando uma api do site ( ip-api.com ).

ele disponibiliza a resposta em json, xml, csv, php.
aqui eu abordo uma resposta em json.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // aqui eu pego o ip da maquina que acessa
    if ($ip) {
        $Ipfind = filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) ; //validação para o formato ip
        $Search_Ip = substr($Ipfind, 0, 17);

          //envio o ip para o site via get e pego os dados via file_get_contents
        //declaro uma variavel ($api_jsonn) contendo os dados da requisição.
        
        $api_jsonn = file_get_contents("http://Ip-api.com/json/" . $Search_Ip);
        

         //os dados da requisição vem em formato json. abaixo deixo um exemplo de resposta. 

        /*{"status":"success","country":"Canada","countryCode":"CA","region":"QC","regionName":"Quebec","city":"Montreal","zip":"H1K","lat":45.6085,"lon":-73.5493,"timezone":"America/Toronto","isp":"Le Groupe Videotron Ltee","org":"Videotron Ltee","as":"AS5769 Videotron Telecom Ltee","query":"24.48.0.1"}*/

     // como esses dados estão contidos na variavel $api_jsonn
     
        $Country1 = explode('"country":"', $api_jsonn);
        // usamos o explode, selecionamos a matriz country que é o pais do ip remoto

        $Country2 = explode('",', $Country1[1]);
       //selecionamos o indice 1 da matriz country e inserimos na variavel $Country2

        $Country = $Country2[0];
       //selecionamos o indice 0 da variavel $Country2

      //pronto! se fizermos um echo $Country; 
     //exibiria o nome do pais em inglês(pode mudar o formato da resposta). 
      //como o intuito é impedir o acesso podemos agora fazer as automações baseados
     // na informação da $country2. Veja o exemplo

     //se $Country2 for diferente de Brazil exiba pais nao permitido
       if($Coutry2 != "Brazil"){
      echo "País não permitido.";
      die('pais nao permitido');
    }
    

    //podemos fazer diversas coisas à partir daqui ok. deixe fluir a imaginação.
        // Lembrando que voces tem mais dados na resposta, como, cidade, codigo //postal(impreciso), provedor de internet, timezone, latitude, longitude e muito mais. 
        
    }
```